# React Context and rerendering component when object state is changed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm currently building a webapp with React hooks and context. I currently have a flow working which uses a reducer to toggles a global state for `isLightTheme` between `true` and `false`. This all works fine and everything updates accordingly/.

Now I'm trying to add a second flow which has an `object`. In the reducer it is visible that the `object` has been updated with a new value. Whenever I try to `return` the new `state` at the end of my `reducer` function, nothing is updated.

Are all `objects` seem as the same by the `reducer`? So it won't update because the `value` is still the same? Is there a workaround for this?

My reducer in which `state` is an `object` which I'm changing with a new value.

```
export const startOfDayReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'UPDATE_CASH_DRAWER_COUNT':
            const { cashDrawers } = state; 
            state.cashDrawers = cashDrawers;
            return state;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning same state from reducer, create copy of state and update value and return it.

```
export const startOfDayReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'UPDATE_CASH_DRAWER_COUNT':
            const { cashDrawers } = action; // assuming you are getting updated cashDrawers from action 
            return { ...state, cashDrawers }; // create new copy of state and return it.
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mmmm so only doing `{ ...state}` already fixed it. I'm not sure I understand the difference between `state` and the destructured `{...state}`

Comment: if you do state === state it will return true but if you do state === {...state} you will get false because {...state} creates shallow copy of your state.

Answer (score 0):

A good rule of thumb when working with useReducer is to “never mutate arguments”, and in react in general: “never mutate state”.

Try returning a new object:
'return {...state, cashDrawers}'

If you can’t use the object spread operator, this is equivalent:
'return Object.assign({}, state, {cashDrawers})'